# Magento 2 EE multi-website vs multi-store

Tags: magento, magento2

I initially set my system up as multi-store on a single website and I'm running into some problems.  Right now I've found I'm having trouble restricting users from specific stores.  I'd also like to have specific payment methods and shipping methods only available to some stores.

I think the last two problems will be solved by making this a multi-website (I will attempt to use the same domain and a different folder structure for each website).

Once its a multi-website set up, is there a good way to only require a user to register once (for all sites), but only allow them access to specific stores set by an admin?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration you are searching is located at

```
Stores->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration
```

You can choose to share accounts either globally or per website.

A logic for restricting access to specific websites still have to be implemented, since it is not built-in. (unless you want to do it manually for each customer)

Comment: This actually would be per custom, is the functionality to prevent / allow them access to a site available by default in that case?

Comment: when you edit a customer you can add/choose accessible websites. But there is no global option to set multiple websites available by default